# New relic to show the errors for all apps togather

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform, nrql

Since we have configured our entire stack as different apps on new relic including for multiple brands. I have to switch apps to check for errors on each one. Is there a way to check for errors on all apps togather in one view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [New Relic Insights](https://newrelic.com/insights) queries to display metrics for up to 1000 applications from the same New Relic account on a timeseries chart:

*Error Count by Application*

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Transaction WHERE errorType IS NOT NULL FACET appName SINCE 1 hour ago TIMESERIES LIMIT 1000
```

*Error Percentage by Application*

```
SELECT percentage(count(*), WHERE errorType IS NOT NULL) FROM Transaction FACET appName SINCE 1 hour ago TIMESERIES LIMIT 1000
```

If you want to explore a variation of these queries, you can use the Insights [Data Explorer](https://blog.newrelic.com/2015/11/12/insights-visual-data-explorer/) which has a UI or modify the [NRQL](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/insights/new-relic-insights/using-new-relic-query-language/get-started-nrql) above.

Then save the chart to an [Insights Dashboard](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/insights/new-relic-insights/managing-dashboards-data/building-insights-dashboards).